# How to change particular label colour in Horizontal Bar Chart using Mp Chart in Android?

Tags: android, charts, axis, mpandroidchart

How can i change the particular label text color in xaxis using Horizontal Bar Chart. Please show the attached screenshot and code.
[[Here is the screen short]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O00ZY.png)

I have changed the bar colour in to black but i have to change that text colour corresponding to that bar(For example:(You#) colour need to be change).The following code i have tried so far.

```
    XAxis xAxis1 = horizontalBarChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis1.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis1.setTextSize(8);
    xAxis1.setSpaceBetweenLabels(8);
    xAxis1.setTypeface(tf);
    YAxis leftAxis = horizontalBarChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setEnabled(false);
    for(int j=0;j<BarEntryLabels1.size();j++){
        if ((BarEntryLabels1.get(j).contains("You"))){
            xAxis1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }else{
            xAxis1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#701112"));
        }
    }
```

Any code and help would be appreciate, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872181/mpandroidchart-bar-chart-how-to-change-color-of-each-label

Comment: Hey no this one is for to change bar colour that i have already changed in to black.

Answer (score 0):

If you wand to change the chart label color then try this code

```
chart.getAxisLeft().setTextColor(...); // left y-axis
chart.getXAxis().setTextColor(...);
chart.getLegend().setTextColor(...);
```

Or you can do by this way [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772646/mpandroidchart-can-i-set-different-colours-for-the-x-axis-labels?noredirect=1&lq=1).
**For more detail about Axis [please check this](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis).**

Comment: No not this one.Already i can able to set the colour.My question is that particular position only.

Comment: You should put your color setting code inside for loop.

Comment: thats what i did in my code please look on my code, xAxis1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); i have added such code