# want two colors when using mpandroidchart line chart with beizer style

Tags: mpandroidchart

I'm drawing a line chart with mpandroidchart and I want my line BELOW zero to be red rather than green.  It's seems that beizer is not respecting the line-color settings (green is first color in my array & thats the only one that gets used).  Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

[image: my current chart]

Comment: since the color should switch from red to green at the point it crosses the zero-line, I'm wondering if I need to forcibly add a ghost point to the data??

Comment: Hey @Deway got any solutions ?

Comment: @Dewey , did you get any solution? I am stuck at same issue. If there is any reference, can you provide any? Any help will be appreciated...